# Remove CVS directories from maven pom especially in combination with serenityBDD

Tags: maven, selenium, jbehave, thucydides, serenity-bdd

I have a `serenityBDD` (former `thucydides`) test project using `JBehave` and `Selenium` which is stored in a `CVS`... but when i run the test execution I also get the `CVS` folders displayed as capabilities/features and stories:

[image: serenityBDD living documentation]

This happens because of the convention-over-configuration feature of `serenityBDD` and it assumes that all the CVS folders which are automatically generated by turtoise cvs are features/stories/whatever.

How can i exclude these folders from execution? I already tried to modify the `POM` and exclude all `CVS` dirs by putting

```
<configuration>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/CVS/**</exclude>
  </excludes>
</configuration>
```

all around the plugins... but that doesn't help me, they are still there.. I think the solution has to be to modify the `mvn pom` but actually i'm not an expert using `mvn`.

This is the `POM` (only the `<build>` and `<profile>` part):

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <configuration> 
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/When*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ENTW</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <copy todir="target/test-classes">
                                            <fileset dir="properties/ENTW">
                                                <include name="**/*.*" />                       
                                            </fileset>
                                        </copy>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Comment: There is not a single `<exclude>` in the POM excerpt you supply. Can you please show the POM _with_ all the `<exclude>`s you tried.

Comment: I posted already the configuration/excludes/exclude command.. I just put it into EVERY plugin und profile and nothing changed. I removed it from the POM because it had no effect. If there is a "special" position where I have to post it then I would be happy if you could tell me